# В чем ошибка при сборке приложения в cordova?

Tags: android, node.js, docker, cordova

У меня есть приложение, пытаюсь его собрать для Android сторов, при настройке автоматической сборки выпадают ошибки, собираю в Docker чтобы потом артифактом передать приложение, собираю раннером типа docker

Мой Dockerfile

```
# ---- Сборка Node.js проекта ----
FROM node:14.21.3 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN npm install -g cordova

# ---- Сборка Cordova ----
FROM android-base as cordova-build
WORKDIR /app

# Копируем собранный Node.js проект
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app/www

# Инициализация Cordova проекта (если требуется)
# RUN cordova create . com.example.app MyApp

# Добавление платформы и сборка
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh && cordova platform add android && cordova build android"
```

Как видно, все достаточно явно описано, хоть я и не разбираюсь в cordova

Вот ошибка в gitlab CI

```
process "/bin/sh -c /bin/bash -c \"source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh && cordova platform add android && cordova build android\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```